# question regarding global variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need  that I can use 1 object of NSString  to  use  in all other files
to access 1 variable in all filees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an unclear question.

If I understand correctly you want to have an global `NSString*` shared by multiple files. In that case, in one of the source files (`.m`), insert

```
NSString* my_global_string = @"...";
```

and in all other source files (or in a common `.h`), insert

```
extern NSString* my_global_string;
```

Answer (score 4):

Make this `NSString` a property of the `AppDelegate` class (or whatever your application delegate class is named). If the property is named `myString`, you can then access it via:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] myString];
```

To avoid warnings, you may want to import the `AppDelegate` class:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

...and expand the first code snippet into:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate myString];
```